# Can not resize or move terminal window or browser windows

Tags: web-browsers, lxterminal

Having an issue I am using as raspberry pi 3. I switch to the desktop open up a terminal window and I do not get the entire window. So I can not drag the terminal window nor resize the window. It is stuck at the top left corner of the screen. I open up the browser and I can't move that window either. I can't go back to the terminal window without closing the browser window. I've tried the alt + dragging with the mouse. I've tried going to settings appearance settings and setting it back to default. I've rebooted multiple times. I did the reboot multiple times because it worked once. Then I had to reboot because the pi was frozen. The mouse pointer is also an x. Any other things to try. I am running noobs.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the solution: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1343713

ReddTedd59@ wrote on raspberrypi.org forum

> I found a way to fix this the retains all of the custom settings I did with obconf. This differs from the solution of resetting to defaults, which also kills all customization's you may have made.
>
> It seems that obconf and the different raspian panel mod tools all end up deleting the <keyboard> and <mouse> sections from ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml. Just go grab those two sections from /etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml and reinsert them into ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml.
>
> once you do that logout and back in and there you go mouse works on windows and all of your other customization's are still there too!

Note: The command `openbox --reconfigure` will reload the config file without you having to logout.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Set Resolution..." under Raspberry Pi Configuration and see if it's set to default. If it is, change the resolution settings to something like `1920x1080`. It will have you `reboot`. After that, the windows should appear normal again.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling everything.